# Replace section with subsection while inputting a beamer file into another one?

Tags: beamer

I try to figure out a good way to build something like modules, that I can input afterwards in different files.

For each topic (= module), I create an own file like `InputFile.tex`:

```
\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}
  Foo Section 1
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{frame}
  Foo Subsection 1
\end{frame}
```

Afterwards I input it in a file like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \input{InputFile}

\end{document}
```

That works.

But now, I want to create `InputFile.tex` in a file that has already sections, the content of `InputFile` should be sub- and subsubsections.

Afterwards I input it in a file like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

  \section{Outersection}

  \input{InputFile}

\end{document}
```

The result (after inputing) should look like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \section{Outersection}

    \subsection{Section 1}

    \begin{frame}
      Foo Section 1
    \end{frame}

    \subsubsection{Subsection 1}

    \begin{frame}
      Foo Subsection 1
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there an elegant way to do so?

Comment: Try to replace `\input{InputFile}` by `{\let\section\subsection\let\subsection\subsubsection\input{InputFile}}`. The extra braces are required such that TeX forgets the `\let`s after having done the `\input`.

Comment: Thank you! That's the solution!